# Creating new Objects inside for loop in Nodejs and assigning it to variable with let?

Tags: node.js

```
for() {
    let obj1 = new Object();
}
```

Is this any different, with regard to performance, from

```
let obj1;
for() {
    obj1 = new Object();
}
```

Comment: As with all performance issues, if you really, really, really care about that possible performance issue, you would have to benchmark a relevant test case in your preferred version of node.js and see if the results make a difference to you. On a theoretical level, declaring `let` inside the `for` loop does have a bit more work to do because it makes a new variable on each iteration of the loop, all of which will have to be garbage collected. Whether this is actually relevant enough to modify your coding style for is unlikely, but if you're trying to micro-optimize, you can measure to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's different, because when using 'let' that variable will only exists inside the for loop and at every iteration you will be creating a new variable.

When you declare the let obj outside the for, it can be used inside and outside the loop.

Check this for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Hope it helped :)